# Webview localStorage.setItem(javascript) cant set before load url(android)

Tags: javascript, android, webview

Before loading my URL, I need to set `localStorage.setItem`.

However, when I load the URL for the first time nothing appears. If I refresh the page a second time, then it appears. How I can set `localStorage.setItem` the first time the page is loaded?

```
webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        //set token and role
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

            @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                webView.loadUrl(
                        "javascript:" +
                                "localStorage.setItem('token', '" + token + "');");
            }

        });


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            private ProgressDialog mProgress;

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                try {
                    if (mProgress == null) {
                        mProgress = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                        if (!getActivity().isFinishing()) {
                            mProgress.show();
                        }
                    }

                    mProgress.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading) + String.valueOf(progress) + "%");
                    if (progress == 100) {
                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        mProgress = null;
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("item menu", e.toString());
                }
            }
        });



        webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: What about evaluateJavaScript method? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo thanks, but it for API 19, i need for API 15

Comment: Hmm, I see... So, what if you load it reverse, so first do : `loadUrl('javascript:localStorage.setItem(...)')` and then in `onPageStarted` method you load your url `loadUrl(url)`.

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo if i do like this `webView.loadUrl("javascript:");` and then in `onPageStarted` load url `loadUrl(url)`. its method `onPageStarted` not called

Answer (score 1):

As you said , local storage data is not appearing for the first time ... I had faced that same problem .... Here is the solution.
Put the localstorage.setItem(key, val) inside both onPageStarted() and onPageFinished() method.

public class AppWebViewClients extends WebViewClient {
private ProgressBar progressBar;

```
    public AppWebViewClients(ProgressBar progressBar) {
        this.progressBar=progressBar;
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('"+ key1 +"','"+ val1 +"');", null);
            webview.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('"+ key2 +"','"+ val2 +"');", null);

        } else {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('"+ key1 +"','"+ val1 +"');");
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('"+ key2 +"','"+ val2 +"');");

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            webview.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('"+ key1 +"','"+ val1 +"');", null);
            webview.evaluateJavascript("window.localStorage.setItem('"+ key2 +"','"+ val2 +"');", null);

        } else {
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('"+ key1 +"','"+ val1 +"');");
            webview.loadUrl("javascript:localStorage.setItem('"+ key2 +"','"+ val2 +"');");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will solve your issue.
Thank You